# como obtener el valor de un select en controlador de codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Estoy tratando de obtener el valor de mi select en el controlador, pero no funciona de esta manera, me dice que el metodo input no existe.

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-static mb-4">
  <label for="tipoVehiculo" class="ms-0">Tipo De Vehiculo</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="tipoVehiculo">
    <option>Coche</option>
    <option>Jeepeta</option>
    <option>Furgoneta</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

En el controlador es asi:

```php
$select= $this->request->input->post('tipoVehiculo');
print_r($select);
```

Codeigniter 4 me lanza este error:

Undefined property: CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest::$input

Ayuda please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aquí tienes 3 opciones:

Utilice el almacenamiento local del navegador @Rohan Kumar
Use una cookie para almacenar sus datos @ usuario8175473
Use PHP/CodeIgniter SESSION para almacenar sus datos @Neeraj Singh :D
El patrón es muy simple: el menú desplegable OnSelect obtiene el valor seleccionado, guarda esos valores en algún lugar al que pueda acceder más tarde. Verifique si ese almacenamiento de partículas tiene algún tipo de valor, obtenga esos valores desde allí y vuelva a colocarlos dentro del menú desplegable nuevamente.

Te lo digo aquí: cómo podríamos usar CodeIgniter Session + jQuery, para recuperar tu valor desplegable.

Su html o vistas:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?php echo site_url("workpackage"); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Client</label>
        <?php echo form_dropdown('wptypes', $wptypes, set_value('wptypes'), 'id="wptypes" class="form-select" onchange="this.form.submit()"'); ?>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // wptypes select box
        var $wptypes     = $('select#wptypes');
        // check on load of wptypes value exist in session
        var _prev_sel_val = "<?=$this->session->userdata('wptypes') ? $this->session->userdata('wptypes') :  '';?>";
        // if not empty, set value
        if(_prev_sel_val){
            $wptypes.val(_prev_sel_val);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Su controlador (ejemplo):

```
<?php
// security first always....
(defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed'));
/**
 * Class Controller
 *
 * Class workpackage Controller to handle login & logout
 */
class Workpackage extends CI_controller
{
    /**
     * Class Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // execute parent class constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * workpackage, Default method to execute if method name missing
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // only on POST Request
        if ($this->input->post('wptypes')) {
            // drop down value
            $wptypes = array(
                'wptypes' => $this->input->post('wptypes', TRUE)
            );
            // set in session
            $this->session->set_userdata( $wptypes );
            // your other stuff do..... here...
        }
    }
}
/* End of file workpackage.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/workpackage.php */
```

Comment: no hay una manera mas facil? soy nuevo y no entiendo muy bien. En los input normal se reciben los datos mas facilmente, tal como :

```  $idEmpleado = $this->request->getPost('idEmpleado');```

Answer (score 0):

Todos los valores que mandas en el formularios deben ir asignados a "**NAME**", el ID solo sirve para hacer referencias.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-static mb-4">
  <label for="tipoVehiculo" class="ms-0">Tipo De Vehiculo</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="tipoVehiculo" name="tipoVehiculo">
    <option>Coche</option>
    <option>Jeepeta</option>
    <option>Furgoneta</option>
  </select>
</div>
```